# Tkinter seems to blur my icon upon opening a second window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that currently runs four windows when a .txt file is not found, and just one when it is. Upon running the code without the text file, the icon for the first window is fine. For the other three, it is blurred. When there is the file, the icon does not blur. It seems to blur upon opening a second window. I wondered if anyone could help?

```
import os
import ctypes
from tkinter import *
configfile = "config.txt"
newname = ""

def accept():
    global errorbox
    errorbox.destroy()

def errorrun(title, message, w, h):
    global errorbox
    errorbox = Tk()
    errorbox.title(title)
    errorbox.iconbitmap(default = "favicon.ico")
    errorlabel = Label(errorbox, text = message).pack()
    errorbutton = Button(errorbox, text = "        Ok        ", command = accept).pack()
    ws = errorbox.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = errorbox.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    errorbox.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    errorbox.mainloop()

def entryapp():
    global newname
    global entrywindow
    global entering
    newname = entering.get()
    entrywindow.destroy()

def entrybox(title, message, w, h):
    global entrywindow
    global entering
    entrywindow = Tk()
    entrywindow.title(title)
    entrywindow.iconbitmap(default = "favicon.ico")
    entrylabel = Label(entrywindow, text = message).pack()
    entering = Entry(entrywindow)
    entering.pack()
    entrylabelgap = Label(entrywindow, text = " ").pack()
    entrybutton = Button(entrywindow, text = "        Ok        ", command = entryapp).pack()
    ws = entrywindow.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = entrywindow.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    entrywindow.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    entrywindow.mainloop()

if os.path.exists(configfile):
    pass
else:
    errorrun("Cannot find file!", "\nThe configuration file was not found.\nCreating one now.\n", 320, 100)
    config = open(configfile,"w")
    config.close()

config = open(configfile,"r")
name = config.readline(1)

if name == "":
    config.close()
    config = open(configfile,"w")
    errorrun("No name detected!", "\nNo name has been detected.\n", 320, 90)
    entrybox("Name entry!", "\nPlease enter your name:\n", 320, 130)
    config.write(newname)

config.close()

def mainmenu():
    mainwindow = Tk()
    mainwindow.iconbitmap(default = "favicon.ico")
    mainwindow.wm_title("Student management system!")
    w = 500
    h = 500
    ws = mainwindow.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = mainwindow.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    mainwindow.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    mainwindow.mainloop()

mainmenu()
```

Comment: This sounds like a window manager issue. What window manager are you using? Though, you're using Tkinter in an unusual way which may contribute to the problem. Typically you should never create more than one instance of `Tk` in a tkinter program, and only ever call `mainloop` once.

Comment: In honesty, I am not sure what a window manager is! I will have a go at changing how the system runs.

Comment: Are the icons the same size for all of the windows?